Error: Cannot initialize detox concept more than once, when running codeceptjs tests
When running my codeceptjs test suite, one test succeeded while another failed to execute due to the error: 'Cannot initialize primary Detox context more than once.
codeceptjs.conf
import { setHeadlessWhen, setCommonPlugins } from '@codeceptjs/configure';
// turn on headless mode when running with HEADLESS=true environment variable
// export HEADLESS=true && npx codeceptjs run
setHeadlessWhen(process.env.HEADLESS);

// enable all common plugins https://github.com/codeceptjs/configure#setcommonplugins
setCommonPlugins();

export const config: CodeceptJS.MainConfig = {
  tests: './tests/*.test.ts',
  output: './output',
  helpers: {
    Detox: {
      require: '@codeceptjs/detox-helper',
      configuration: 'ios.sim.debug',
    }
  },

  include: {
    I: './steps_file'
  },
  name: 'e2e'
}


.detoxrc.js
/** @type {Detox.DetoxConfig} */
module.exports = {
behavior: {
init: {
  reinstallApp: false,
  exposeGlobals: true
}
},
  apps: {
    'ios.debug': {
      type: 'ios.app',
      binaryPath: "binaryPath",
      build: "xcodebuild",

    },

    'ios.release': {
      type: 'ios.simulator',
      binaryPath: "binaryPath",
      build: "xcodebuild",

    },


  },
  devices: {
    simulator: {
      type: 'ios.simulator',
      device: {
        type: 'iPhone 15 Pro'
      }
    },

  },
  configurations: {
    'ios.sim.debug': {
      device: 'simulator',
      app: 'ios.debug'
    },

    'ios.sim.release': {
      device: 'simulator',
      app: 'ios.release'
    },



  }
};



I have 2 tests file with same steps in Scenario but different scenario name:
const {I} = inject()

Feature("this is login")


Scenario("login with user", async ()=> {
    I.click("Alrighty! ")
    I.click("Close")
    I.click("SEARCH")
    I.fillField('#HeaderSearchBar', 'test')
})

All the tests should be executed. I am not sure if this error is occurring due to the "No Mocha support".
